# Issue with AMDpro rendering

Tags: rendering, gpu

[image]

I don't know why is this tearing kind of maze thingy on rendered view on AMD renderer
why isn't the view clearer my GPU is AMD RX 580
the view is fine on cycles render I don't know what am I missing cuz I'm new to blender
any help would be appreciated

Comment: AMD RX 480 and 580 GPUs have already been known to have some sort of problem when rendering in Cycles.

Comment: Ok but rendering was done by AMDpro right so whats going on here ?